# OnLongPress popup witha list of options react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to add a functionality to aa button where long press results in opening of a popup where user can choose from multiple options. I wanted to know if there is any component available that renders that prop because AFAIK onLongPress of TouchableHighlight(or Opacity)is non renderable. I understand I can change the state and display another view but I want to make the menu transparent so that clicking(or tapping) on the background results in disappearance of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

The [react-native-popover](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-popover) project looks like it could be an option for you. A note of caution is that I'm not sure how actively maintained it is at the moment. For example, the current version is 0.3.0 but only 0.2.0 is released to npm. To correct that in the interim, see this [issue](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-popover/issues/8).

At a minimum, you can at least review this code as it accomplishes what I believe you're after. Here is a code sample extended off the project site that creates a popover component on a button with a transparent background. When the background is tapped, the popover closes.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Popover from 'react-native-popover';

class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.onLongPress = this.onLongPress.bind(this);
    this.onClose = this.onClose.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isVisible: false,
      buttonRect: {}
    }
  }

  onLongPress () {
    this._button.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
      this.setState({
        isVisible: true,
        buttonRect: {x: px, y: py, width: width, height: height}
      });
    });
  }

  onClose () {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          ref={(component) => this._button = component}
          style={styles.button}
          onLongPress={this.onLongPress}>
          <Text>Long Press Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Popover
          isVisible={this.state.isVisible}
          fromRect={this.state.buttonRect}
          onClose={this.onClose}
          backgroundStyle={styles.popoverBackground}>
          <Text>I'm the content of this popover!</Text>
        </Popover>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    padding: 20
  },

  popoverBackground: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```